# How do I prove the following property of summation formally?

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction, definition

The universe is the set of integers.

We will define summation in the following way:

$\sum_{x=a}^{b}f(x)=f(a)+\sum_{x=a+1}^{b}f(x)$ if $a\leq b$, and equals $0$ otherwise.

How can I prove that

$\forall a\forall b(a\leq b \implies\sum_{x=a}^{b}f(x)=f(b)+\sum_{x=a}^{b-1}f(x))$?

Here is what I have tried:

By the (or maybe one of, I'm not too sure) definition of inequality of integers, we have $\forall a\forall b(a\leq b \iff \exists n\in \mathbb{N}:a+n=b)$, therefore:

$\forall a\forall b(\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:b=a+n \implies\sum_{x=a}^{b}f(x)=f(b)+\sum_{x=a}^{b-1}f(x))$

$\forall a\forall b\forall n\in \mathbb{N}(b=a+n \implies\sum_{x=a}^{b}f(x)=f(b)+\sum_{x=a}^{b-1}f(x))$

$\forall a\forall b\forall n\in \mathbb{N}(b=a+n \implies\sum_{x=a}^{a+n}f(x)=f(a+n)+\sum_{x=a}^{a+n-1}f(x))$

$\forall a\forall n\in \mathbb{N}(\exists b:b=a+n \implies\sum_{x=a}^{a+n}f(x)=f(a+n)+\sum_{x=a}^{a+n-1}f(x))$

$\forall a\forall n\in \mathbb{N}(true \implies\sum_{x=a}^{a+n}f(x)=f(a+n)+\sum_{x=a}^{a+n-1}f(x))$

$\forall a\forall n\in \mathbb{N}(\sum_{x=a}^{a+n}f(x)=f(a+n)+\sum_{x=a}^{a+n-1}f(x))$

From here I tried induction on n. Proving the base case is trivial, so let's just skip to the inductive step.

$\forall a\forall n\in \mathbb{N}(\sum_{x=a}^{a+n}f(x)=f(a+n)+\sum_{x=a}^{a+n-1}f(x) \implies \sum_{x=a}^{a+n+1}f(x)=f(a+n+1)+\sum_{x=a}^{a+n}f(x))$

This is where I am stuck. Maybe I should have used strong induction instead?

Comment: Call the proposition to proven $\forall a,b \;P(a,b).$ The cases $a>b$ and $a= b$ are obvious.  Suppose by contradiction that $a<b$ and $\neg P(a,b).$ Let $a'=\max \{x<b: \neg P(x,b)\}$ and $b'=\min \{y> a':\neg P(a',y)\}.$ We have $P(a'+1,b')$ and $P(a',b'-1). $ Can we now deduce $P(a',b')$?